# Converting a wrapper object to a value object

Tags: java, converting, spring, rest

I have `ChannelWrapper` and Channel Value Object. I want to convert each and every field of `ChannelWrapper` to Channel Value Object.

```
public class ChannelWrapper extends BaseWrapper implements APIWrapper<Channel>,
        APIUnwrapper<Channel> {

    @XmlElement
    private Long id;

    @XmlElement
    private User user;

    @XmlElement
    private Tenant tenant;

// Getter Setters
    @Override
    public Channel unwrap(HttpServletRequest arg0, ApplicationContext arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void wrapDetails(Channel model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    this.id = model.getId();
    this.user = model.getUser();
    this.tenant = model.getTenant();

    }


    @Override
    public void wrapSummary(Channel model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    wrapDetails(model, request);

}
```

Channel Value Object:

```
public class Channel {

    private Long id;
    private User user;
    private Tenant tenant;
    //getter setters   }
```

Converter:

```
Channel channel = new Channel();
channel.setId(channelWrapper.getId());
channel.setUser(channelWrapper.getUser());
channel.setTenant(tenant);
```

Is this the best way to create a converter?

Any other general comments are appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get your point. You have a wrapper, a.k.a. [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), for a `Channel`, `ChannelWrapper.` Now you'd like to wrap this wrapper into another wrapper (or _converter_ as you call it) such leading to a `ChannelWrapperWrapper` or `ChannelWrapperAdapter`. And you'd like to call it `ChannelValueObject`? Isn't that a bit confusing and/or over-engineered?

Answer (score 3):

Since both classes have the same getters and setters this can most easily be achieved using [apache commons beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/):

```
Channel channel = new Channel();
BeanUtils.copyProperties(channel, channelWrapper);
```

if you have more complex requirements (e.g. different property names or types), I would recommend [dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).